# Decreasing number pyramid, nested for loop, user input, java

Tags: java

Write a program to produce the following output for any given integer number between
1 and 9 inclusive.

Enter an integer value [1..9]: 6

```
1
12
123
1234
12345
123456
666666
66666
6666
666
66
6
```

I have done the top half but I can not figure out the bottom with the repeating user input.

```
package lab7;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class problem5 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan =  new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Input an integer between 1 and 9");
        int input = scan.nextInt();
        while (input <= 9) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= input; i++) {
                for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                    System.out.print(j);
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            break; 
        }
    }   
}
```

Expected result: included at the top; actual result so far (input of 5):

```
1
12
123
1234
12345
```

Comment: You need to memorize the deep of your pyramid when you reach the selected number. Then you do a new loop decreasing this deep

Comment: :s/deep/depth/g

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty close. You have a `for` loop that covers the first half of the output you want. You can add a second `for` loop to handle the second half of the output.

This is pretty similar to the first loop, but has a few small differences:

- instead of the loop variable starting at 1 and increasing, this one starts at `input` and *decreases* each time through (`i--` instead of `i++`)
- instead of printing any of the loop variables (`i` or `j`), it prints the `input` value ("6" in your example)

```
for (int i = input; i > 0; i--) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        System.out.print(input);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

If I run that code locally – so your `for` loop, then this `for` loop, then the `break` statement – this is the output:

```
Input an integer between 1 and 9
6
1
12
123
1234
12345
123456
666666
66666
6666
666
66
6
```

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer a more efficient algorithm, your current approach is O(n<sup>2</sup>); consider the digits '1' - '9'; if we store them in a `String` then we can take a simple substring of that `String` for each line at the top (for example, "123456789".substring(0, 3) -> "123") that can be used to generate the top through successive calls to `substring`. We can use a similar approach to build the bottom; use an array of all possible rows and iteratively call `substring`. Finally, don't forget to validate that `input` is **between** one and nine inclusive. Something like,

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String digits = "123456789";
String[] btm = { "1", "22", "333", "4444", "55555", 
        "666666", "7777777", "88888888", "999999999" };
System.out.println("Input an integer between 1 and 9");
int input = scan.nextInt();
if (input < 1 || input > 9) {
    System.err.printf("Invalid input: %d%n", input);
    System.exit(1);
}
for (int i = 0; i < input; i++) {
    System.out.println(digits.substring(0, i + 1));
}
for (int i = input - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    System.out.println(btm[input - 1].substring(0, i + 1));
}
```